# How to scrape for specific HTML span elements that get loaded with JQuery

Tags: jquery, python, html, lxml

I am writing a python app that scrapes sensor data from a web-app that I made. I want to use lxml to gather certain span elements from the HTML that get updated periodically with a JQuery script. It seems as though lxml does not grab the text that gets updated with JQuery because I only retrieve the empty string that the original HTML is loaded with. The values from JQuery are reflected when viewing the webpage, but not on the web scraping tool.  How can I consistently retrieve the data that is being updated with JQuery?

HTML

```
            <!--Blower Speed Well -->
            <div class = "col-xs-4">
                <div class = "well" id="bspeed_well">
                    <span class = "tex" id="bspeed_text">Blower Speed: </span>
                    <span class = "val" id="bspeed_data"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JQuery to update HTML element

```
//Gather Data from main.xml and store into variables
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "static/main.xml",
    //dataType: "xml",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function(xml){
        $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
            var id = $(this).find('id').text();
            switch(id){
                   case "blower_speed":
                    bspeed = $(this).find('value').text();
                    break;
        }
});
$("#bspeed_data").text(bspeed);
```

Python lxml query

```
page = requests.get('http://192.168.1.72:5000')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
blower_speed = tree.xpath('//span[@id="bspeed_data"]/text()')
print "Blower Speed: ", blower_speed
```

Result

> Blower Speed:  []

Comment: Where does the `bspeed` value coming from? Is jquery making a separate request to get the value?

Comment: Yes. JQuery makes an ajax request to get the value from an XML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> JQuery makes an ajax request to get the value from an XML document.

You need to *simulate* that AJAX request with `requests`. You can either do it manually, or copy the request as cURL (from the browser developer tools->network tab) and use this [cURL-to-requests conversion utility](http://curl.trillworks.com/) to auto-generate the requests code.

Then, you can use `lxml.etree` to parse the XML response and extract the `bspeed` value.

Comment: I am on the "network tab" in developer tools but since I am unfamiliary with cURL I am somewhat confused on where to find this request.  Does it look something like this?...

Request URL:http://192.168.1.72:5000/static/main.xml?_=1467816070831

Comment: @NickSchrock should be something like that. Sorry, I have no way to reproduce it and could not be any more specific..